# Настройка виртуального хоста. Ошибка 403. Apache 2.2, CentOS 6

Tags: apache, centos, virtual-hosts

Создал виртуальный хост

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.site.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test

    <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Который заворачивает домен 3го уровня `http://test.site.ru` на подкаталог: `http://site.ru/test`. Виртуальный хост поднялся, но на всё выдаёт 403ю ошибку. При этом на основном домене страницу: `http://site.ru/test` открывает нормально.
Где стоит проверить разрешения?

Информация Apache о настроенных виртуальных хостах:

```
[root@www httpd]# /usr/sbin/httpd -S
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using www.site.ru for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server www.site.ru (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1021)
     port 80 namevhost www.site.ru (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1021)
             alias site.ru
     port 80 namevhost test.site.ru (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1030)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: *заворачивает домен 3го уровня на подкаталог: site.ru/test* — из преведённой документации следует, что *docroot*-ом служит каталог `/var/www/test`, без каких-либо упоминаний строки `site.ru`.

Comment: docroot для http://site.ru -> /var/www

Comment: с учётом, что это *redhat-осно́вный* дистрибутив, в которых по умолчанию включен *selinux*, в первую очередь стоит проинспектировать лог-файл *selinux-а*. и, в любом случае, лог-файл *http-сервера*.

Comment: новые вводные - такая реакция на любой поддомен: `http://hello123.site.ru`, даже неопределённый через VirtualHost

Comment: проверьте, во что резолвятся все эти имена в той системе, из которой вы делаете *http-запросы*.

Comment: всё резолвится в IP site.ru

Comment: тогда следующим шагом проконтролируйте, куда уходят пакеты, и приходят ли они на нужную машину.

Comment: Всё приходит в Apache. Какая-то заковырка c VirtualHost в  httpd.conf.

Comment: вероятно, есть другие блоки *virtualhost*. в логи вы, видимо, так и не посмотрели.

Comment: знать бы куда смотреть.. я программист - подадминить вынужденно приходится

Comment: @alexanderbarakin,
[root@www httpd]# /usr/sbin/httpd -S

httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using www.site.ru for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:

wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost

         default server www.site.ru (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1021)

         port 80 namevhost www.site.ru (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1021)
                 alias site.ru
         port 80 namevhost test.site.ru (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1030)
Syntax OK

Comment: форматированный текст, увы, нечитабелен в комментариях. внесите дополнение в вопрос, пожалуйста.